# Strange stereometry

Tags: geometry, volume

A cube-shaped vessel with a 6 cm rib filled with water was turned through an angle of 90 degrees relative to one of the sides of the base. Find how much water remained outside the vessel.

I literally don't know what to do. I tried to calculate volume via proections,but with no success. I need detailed explanation.

Comment: Changing the parameters of a problem after it has been answered is bad form, as it makes the answerers look as though they have misunderstood the question. ... Here, changing "$3$cm" to "$6$cm" is rather inconsequential. However, changing "$60^\circ$" to "$90^\circ$" and "how much water remained *in* the vessel" to "how much water remained *outside* the vessel" is dramatic. (I should think that tipping the vessel $90^\circ$ would empty it. I'm not sure how I would interpret "how much water remained outside the vessel"; are you asking how much water *spilled*?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The volume of the remaining water forms a prism with a right triangular base.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You can use a planar figure as with a cube, you are just sweeping the planar figure along the rotated edge.

Then the water on the planar figure is representing a rectangle triangle for which the area is not difficult to be computed.